# python passing list reference to a function

Tags: python, list, function, arguments, glade

in python I have the following code inside a class:

```
def __init__(self):
    presets = []
    for i in range(6):
        presets.append(dbuilder.get_object("button_pres"+str(i)))
        presets[i].connect("clicked", self.on_preset_button, i, presets)
        print presets

def on_preset_button(self, origin, i, presets):
    recall(i)
    print presets
```

Now when I call print presets in the for loop, I get the correct result with the list growing every iteration.

However in on_preset_button I get the empty list. I thought I was passing the reference to presets to the function connect, which in turn passes the reference on to on_preset_button. But it seems not.

I want to access the 6 elements I appended to presets before. Please help!

Here's the long version:

```
import gtk

from galicaster.core import context
from galicaster.utils.visca import recall

class DistribUI(gtk.Box):
    __gtype_name__ = 'DistribUI'

    def __init__(self):
        gtk.Box.__init__(self)
        dbuilder= gtk.Builder()
        dbuilder.add_from_file(get_ui_path('distrib.glade'))
        self.builder = dbuilder

        # other gui elements omitted

        presets = []
        for i in range(6):
            presets.append(dbuilder.get_object("button_pres"+str(i)))
            presets[i].connect("clicked", self.on_preset_button, i, presets)
            print presets

    def on_preset_button(self, origin, i, presets):
            recall(i)
            print presets
```

Here's the output after loading the class:

```
[<gtk.Button object at 0x204ab40 (GtkButton at 0x20ad330)>]
[<gtk.Button object at 0x204ab40 (GtkButton at 0x20ad330)>, <gtk.Button object at 0x204ab90 (GtkButton at 0x20ad4b0)>]
[<gtk.Button object at 0x204ab40 (GtkButton at 0x20ad330)>, <gtk.Button object at 0x204ab90 (GtkButton at 0x20ad4b0)>, <gtk.Button object at 0x204ac30 (GtkButton at 0x20ad630)>]
[<gtk.Button object at 0x204ab40 (GtkButton at 0x20ad330)>, <gtk.Button object at 0x204ab90 (GtkButton at 0x20ad4b0)>, <gtk.Button object at 0x204ac30 (GtkButton at 0x20ad630)>, <gtk.Button object at 0x204acd0 (GtkButton at 0x20ad3f0)>]
[<gtk.Button object at 0x204ab40 (GtkButton at 0x20ad330)>, <gtk.Button object at 0x204ab90 (GtkButton at 0x20ad4b0)>, <gtk.Button object at 0x204ac30 (GtkButton at 0x20ad630)>, <gtk.Button object at 0x204acd0 (GtkButton at 0x20ad3f0)>, <gtk.Button object at 0x204ad70 (GtkButton at 0x20ad570)>]
[<gtk.Button object at 0x204ab40 (GtkButton at 0x20ad330)>, <gtk.Button object at 0x204ab90 (GtkButton at 0x20ad4b0)>, <gtk.Button object at 0x204ac30 (GtkButton at 0x20ad630)>, <gtk.Button object at 0x204acd0 (GtkButton at 0x20ad3f0)>, <gtk.Button object at 0x204ad70 (GtkButton at 0x20ad570)>, <gtk.Button object at 0x204ae10 (GtkButton at 0x20ad6f0)>]
```

And here's the output after clicking on button 1 for example:

```
[]
10 OK - no return value
```

The last line is the result of recall(i), which is an external subprocess. And just before that you can see the empty list :(

Comment: Try printing `presets` inside `__init__`.

Comment: What is `dbuilder`? It looks like that framework is doing something to your list that doesn't support your usecase.

Comment: dbuilder works with glade and creates gui elements from xml files. ie: I declare a GtkButoon element in the glade file. Then in python I can use dbuilder to build the button using its id, which is button_pres[0-5] in my case.

Comment: All 6 buttons show up in the gui and clicking on them does the intended thing: recall(i) in the second function is correctly executed.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you post your log here , source code is better.
Sounds like connect function did something before on_preset_button is called